# realloc error in C when resizing the heap

Tags: c, heap

I want to use realloc in C in an insert function for heap. This is the code:

```
typedef struct MaxHeap {
    int size;
    int* heap;
} MaxHeap;

void max_insert(MaxHeap* max_heap, int* key_index, int key) { // O(logn)
    max_heap->heap = realloc((max_heap->size+1), sizeof * max_heap->heap);
    max_heap[max_heap->size] = N_INF;
    max_heap->size += 1;
    increase_key(max_heap, key_index, max_heap->size, key)
}
```

And I get this warning:

`warning: passing argument 1 of ‘realloc’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]` and I tried this fix:

```
max_heap->heap = realloc((max_heap->heap), (max_heap->size+1) * sizeof(*(max_heap->heap)));
```

**Update**

I did this:

```
void max_insert(MaxHeap* max_heap, int* key_index, int key) { // O(logn)
    int* temp = realloc (max_heap->heap, (max_heap->size + 1) * sizeof (*(max_heap->heap)));
    if (!temp) exit(1);
    max_heap->heap = temp;
    max_heap->heap[max_heap->size] = N_INF;
    max_heap->size += 1;
    increase_key(max_heap, key_index, max_heap->size, key);
    temp = 0;
}
```

And I got this error `realloc(): invalid old size`

Comment: NEVER `realloc()` to the original pointer. When (not if) `realloc()` fails, you overwrite the original pointer address with `NULL`, losing the address and creating a *memory-leak*. ALWAYS `realloc()` using a temporary pointer, e.g. `void *tmp = realloc (max_heap->heap, new_size);` and validate the `realloc()` succeeds before assigning to the original pointer, e.g. `if (!tmp) { perror ("realloc-max_heap->heap"); /* handle the error, e.g. return NULL */ };` on success assign `max_heap->heap = tmp;`. If you alloc in a function, it must have a return type to indicate success/failure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've swapped the arguments to `realloc()`.

```
(max_heap->size+1)
```

evaluates to an `int`, but the first argument to `realloc()` expects a `void *` pointer. Replace it with:

```
(max_heap->heap);
```

And the call to `realloc()` becomes:

```
realloc (max_heap->heap, (max_heap->size + 1) * sizeof (*(max_heap->heap)));
```

Note that this fails for two reasons:

1. There was not enough memory and `realloc()` returned `NULL`, which will go unnoticed because we didn't check the return value of `realloc()`. A subsequent operation would now be writing to / dereferencing / reading from `NULL`, which would invoke undefined behaviour.
2. If `realloc()` returned `NULL`, we would lose access to the original memory, which would result in a memory leak.

**Fix:**

Use a temporary pointer to hold the return value of `realloc()`:

```
int *tmp = realloc (... , ...);

if (!tmp) {
    perror ("realloc()");
    /* realloc() was unable to allocate memory.
     * The original memory is left untouched.
     * Handle error here.
     */
} 
/* Now we can assign the result to `max_heap->heap`: */
max_heap->heap = tmp;
tmp = 0;      /* This is unnecessary, but eliminates a dangling pointer. */
```

Comment: Was `max_heap()` not already allocated with `malloc()` or a similar function? The question said *resizing*. How was this `insert` function called? Kindly edit the question and provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: That was the problem yes, I fixed it.

Comment: Do note that it's bad design, and lazy, for library code to abort a program, and that too without printing an error message. The standard library functions on error return an error code on allocation failure, they do not abort the program. Consider doing the same. Your `insert()` function could be declared to return a `bool` type instead of `void`, and return `true` on success, and `false` elsewise. The library user can then decide whether to exit the program or not. And consider accepting the answer if it you found the solution helpful.